# Error 404 Display on otherlinks apart from homepage

Tags: admin, 404-error, domain, hosting, web-services

i transfered wp hosting to godaddy only the homepage displays i get 404 error when click on other links.. (The domain name is hosted on namecheap tho and i changed name server from the former hosting company to godaddy) but just the homepage displays...

Answer (score 0):

If your site uses permalinks, try going to Settings > Permalinks and then click on Save. It will refresh your permalinks and will typically solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload .htaccess file on root folder.
First create file with name ".htaccess".

Paste below code to this created file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Save and upload on server to root directory.